# SQL stream sort multiple tables together

Tags: sql, sorting

Assume I have multiple tables, for simplicity lets say there are 3 tables.  Each table have the same number of columns/data types and are already sorted.  For this example lets say its sorted by column time.  I would like to query each table and merge sort them all together and get the results in chunks or by streaming.  I say streaming since lets assume the 3 tables are extremely large, so would like to get some results without first sorting the entire thing first

For example lets say we have tables

table1

```
time   |  name  |  age
 1     |  carl  |  15
 4     |  karl  |  16
 11    |  john  |  23
```

table2

```
time  |  name  |  age
 2    |  jess  |  10
 4    |  kara  |  20
 9    |  mike  |  30
```

table3

```
time   |  name  |  age
 3     |  sara  |  15
 5     |  pam   |  25
 7     |  sam   |  35
```

results

```
time   |  name  |  age
 1     |  carl  |  15
 2     |  jess  |  10
 3     |  sara  |  15
 4     |  karl  |  16
 4     |  kara  |  20
 5     |  pam   |  25
 7     |  sam   |  35
 9     |  mike  |  30
 11    |  john  |  23
```

Querying chunks, say limit each by 50, then UNION and then SORT, seems inefficient.  Also, what if table1 has times much earlier than the time in table2 and table3, then this wont work.

Comment: I know you're using a very simple example to try and demonstrate - but sometimes it's good to understand better the structure of the 3 tables that you're working with, and understanding the business case behind the need to combine the data.  That said, if your underlying tables are indexed on the appropriate columns, then you could build a CTE from (SELECT TOP 50 * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT TOP 50 * FROM table2 UNION ALL SELECT TOP 50 * FROM table3), then select the TOP 'x' amount that you need from the CTE with appropriate ordering.  Performance on that should be OK

Comment: Although, you haven't specifically said whether the required number of rows will be the same all the time (ie. 50), or a variable number.  And also you haven't specified whether there'll be certain WHERE clause criteria that will also apply.  The addition of any of those factors will increase the complexity slightly

Comment: With your solution, how would you get the second 50, and the rest? I only picked an arbitrary number of 50, but I would ultimately like to get the results of the entire 3 tables combined/sorted at the end.

Comment: I'll post an answer, so that you can see the code sensibly - you'll then be able to determine if it meets your needs or not

Comment: Tables are not sorted.  They represent *unordered* (multi)sets.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TOP 50 [time], [name], [age]
    FROM [table1]
    -- ORDER BY [time] -- uncomment the ORDER BY if [time] is not the PK or default index
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 50 [time], [name], [age]
    FROM [table2]
    -- ORDER BY [time] -- ditto
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 50 [time], [name], [age]
    FROM [table3]
    -- ORDER BY [time] -- ditto
)
SELECT
    TOP 50
    [time], [name], [age]
FROM cte
ORDER BY [time];
```

I'm making the assumption that [time] will be indexed appropriately, so that the individual SELECTs in the CTE will run quickly.  So, by having a maximum 150 records in the CTE and then selecting the TOP 50 from those, it doesn't matter whether (for example) [table2] actually has the lowest 50 [time] values, or they are evenly spread over the 3 tables.

This is my interpretation of what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Question, if the 3 tables have 10 million each, this process will extract then combine the entire 30 million first, then sort, then give me results right? So before I get any results, it has to go through all the data first? Again i am not just getting top X data, I would like to get the entire data sorted. The only reason I picked a 50 number was just because i would like to get some results right away without sorting/merging all the data first, but ultimately I want all the data sorted/merged, and not just get a fraction of the data